# Connecting a PIC32MZ with an Android tablet via USB

Tags: usb, pic, usb-device, android

I have an Allview tablet running Android I want to connect to my board using USB. An application on the Android tablet would control the micro which in turn would control a bunch of relays and read from a bunch of sensors.

I have routed the +5V, GND, USB_ID and USB_DATA1/2 pins to a connector but I am not sure how to set up the pins on this micro USB connector so that the tablet can talk with my micro and also charge its battery from my board.

Some people say it's going to work with an OTG adapter, which basically pulls down the sense pin to GND. But how does the tablet charge its battery? The connection will be long term/permanent so the tablet needs power.

I have seen a lot of tutorials and specs out there but they are convoluted bricks of text with a lot of ifs and buts so I still don't quite understand: Do I pull down the USB_ID/sense pin to GND? If that's the case my understanding is the tablet would supply power to the board which I don't want, I want the tablet to charge from the board because it will run out of battery eventually.

The board can and must supply some 500mA at +5V to the tablet using the micro USB connector.

Would appreciate some tips from someone more experienced with the USB bus architecture.

Comment: Slightly different question. With the Allview tablet were you able to enable adb

Comment: I'm not sure what that is but the manufacturer indicated an OTG cable must be used. Which is alright except still no option to power the tablet.

Comment: Adb - Android debugging Bridge. Some android tablets like Samsung Tables have Security software that prevents activating the _adb_ . Thus I was just wondering. Note _adb_ is activated via the USB port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USB / USB OTG doesn't give you much of an option here – the *device* never powers the *host*, so you can't charge your tablet while it's the host to an OTG device – at least as long as the tablet behaves standards-compliant (and I'd argue doing that here would be *a very good idea*, because drawing power from a device sounds like a very bad idea if the device doesn't want to be a charger, as it can damage the device.)

So, I don't see a way to do what you want.

Comment: so how does it work when you hook up a phone/tablet to a computer and it charges at the same time with loading stuff?

Comment: then the tablet is the device, and the computer is the host.

Comment: is there anything stopping my pic32 from operating in the same way?

Comment: Yes. You need your PIC32 to be the device, functionally. So it can't be the host. End of story, really.

Comment: So I'm guessing it's all software and all I need is a plain dumb usb cable?

Comment: NO: for the last time, it doesn't work like you want it to. If you want to charge your tablet, it must be in the *device* role. If you want your table to talk to a microcontroller as peripheral, the tablet needs to be in the *host* role. It can only be one of that. **What you want is impossible.** And especially, not something that software can do.

Comment: Oh ok. So following the line of thought it doesn't actually work with the computer - charging and transferring files or whatever.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with that?  (and especially, how that is not answered by my answer / previous comments)

Comment: Well, I am able right now to charge the tablet AND transfer files at the same time from both my mac or my windows pc. I want to do the same except instead of mac/windows I want my pic32 there talking to the tablet, host or no host, device or no device, OTG or not, I don't really care how as long as it does what I want: charge and exchange data at the same time.

Comment: well, that doesn't work, even if you managed to get a full USB host, mass storage driver, file system driver, and application logic inside the relatively dumb pic32, because the way PC and tablet can exchange information in that mode of operation is through completely copied files, and there's no guarantees whatsoever on atomicity or any form of synchronizity. In short, when your PC copies a file to your tablet, there's no guarantee it will be complete until you clicked the "eject device" button and waited for all transfers to be complete. And then you'd have to disconnect and reconnect.

Comment: ... and so, you'd have no way to send "commands" to the tablet, or receive data from the tablet. At that point, simply adding wifi to your PIC32Z and the pic32 and the tablet simply exchanging emails over the internet would work better, significantly.

Comment: TL;DR: doesn't work like you want it to. Your tablet needs to be host. Your pic needs to be device. Devices can't charge hosts. We're turning in circles.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much Marcus this was most useful and enlightening!